# How to update field values in angular based on condition in angularjs v1

Tags: angularjs

I have two fields field 1 and field 2 . Field 1 values are yes or no. If field 1 is yes, then i want to update field 2 to some static text( AVAILABLE) .If field 1 is No, then i want to update field 2 as NOT AVAILABLE. How to achieve this?

Comment: can you add some example of your code? then I can complete it

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf

Comment: <span class="field1">FIELD 1 </span><span class="field1">YES </span>
<span class="field2">FIELD 2</span><span class="field1">AVAILABLE </span>

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that by field you mean some html
first field is a select

```
<select ng-model="field1" ng-init="field1='no'" ng-change="field1changed()">
 <option value="yes">Yes</option>
 <option value="no">No</option>
</select>

<span> {{field2}} </span>
```

and in angularjs/javascript code you may have this function

```
$scope.field1changed = function(){
 if($scope.field1 == 'yes'){
 $scope.field2 == 'some value' 
}
}
```

Comment: Its not select tag, its just a span tag with values binded from backend

Comment: <span class="field1"> FIELD 1 : </span> <span class="field1"> {{data.field1}}

Comment: ok, if I understand rigth this is the solution for you
<span class="field1" ng-model="field1">FIELD 1 </span>
<span class="field1" ng-click="field1 == 'yes'">YES </span>
<span class="field1" ng-click="field1 == 'no'">NO </span>
<span class="field2">FIELD 2</span>
<span class="field1" ng-show="field1 == 'yes'">AVAILABLE </span>
<span class="field1" ng-show="field1 == 'no'">NOT AVAILABLE </span>

Answer (score 0):

Maybe take a look at ng-if?

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf

You could do something like:

```
<div ng-if="model.field1 == 'yes'">AVAILABLE</div>
<div ng-if="model.field1 == 'no'">NOT AVAILABLE</div>
```

Another way that you could do what you want is:

```
<div>{{ model.field1 == 'yes' ? 'AVAILABLE' : model.field1 == 'no' ? 'NOT AVAILABLE' : 'UNKNOWN AVAILABILITY' }}</div>
```

Comment: AVAILABLE and NOT AVAILABLE should be binded to second field